# Vertical Divider not Extending to full Height in Flutter List Tile

Tags: android, listview, flutter

I wanted to recreate my List UI like the one in the following Pic:

[image]

As you can see the Leading Icon in the List tile has a vertical divider to its right side and it is intersected with the bottom divider, but I'm not able to achieve that look and I'm only able to recreate this UI.

[image]

Here is the Code I'm Using:

```
contentBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getFoodDetails(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      dense: false,
                      leading: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.blue),
                          VerticalDivider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].foodTitle),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].foodQuantity),
                      onTap: () {},
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                          color: Colors.yellow, size: 30.0),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }
```

Please suggest how can i Achieve the Desired UI Look with the Dividers proeprly intersecting with each other and remove the padding which im obtaining.

Comment: I think this is how it is, you may have to create your own custom `ListTile` to achieve that.

Comment: for the dividers i have to wrap it in some container and give them borders?

Comment: execute `flutter run` command from the terminal window and press `p` key, what do you see?

Comment: Please look at the following. [image](https://imgur.com/a/pJbT3sI)

Comment: so it explains everything why your `VerticalDivider` does not cover the full height... - for example use `SizedBox` to make your `leading` widget expand to the full height of parent box

Comment: so there is no height property of verticaldivider how can i expand its height? or is there any padding which is being applied which i can cancel?

Comment: I Tried using sized box but maybe I didn't quite get how you wanted me to use it, I'm sorry, I have just started out with flutter so I have to learn a lot, here is the code which I tried but i could not get proper result, please have a look [code](https://imgur.com/a/qKlCNtn)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I tried that and it is also not giving me the desired results, the width just gives more padding to the leading and it is looking bad but the height issue is not fixed, please have a look at this [image](https://imgur.com/a/17ydOc0)

Comment: its not working, I think if possible could you look at my code, i have shared on [github](https://github.com/rohit901/bits_su_app), also here is my flutter version: [flutter](https://imgur.com/a/4zNZOf3)

Comment: what is not working? did you use my code **without** any changes? what is not working then?

Comment: Im really sorry, your code is giving me the desired effect as required, i had not used it exactly earlier and had changed few part as i was using dynamic data and not static data, but then now i used it exactly and it is giving me the desired results thank you so much, but would it work with my current scenario where it is dynamic elements? because i had tried modifying my code according to the code which you had shared, the vertical divider was not extending fully in that case i wonder why

Comment: also how can i also add a divider in my first element of the list as in the picture itself?

Comment: and why dont you use `BoxDecoration` instead of those dividers?

Comment: I think i will try that, I had tried them but i wasn't able to make them work properly, will try again

Comment: having a subtitle text is not letting me get the desired UI effect, is there any way to have the lines intersecting with subtitle also present?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution that I can think of here is to wrap your row in [`IntrinsicHeight()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) if you are using [`VerticalDivider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VerticalDivider-class.html) as separator in Row widget like the sample below:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text('Hello'),
      VerticalDivider(
        color: Colors.black,
        thickness: 2,
      ),
      Text('World'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contentBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getFoodDetails(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 80,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.blue),
                    Container(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Text(snapshot.data[index].foodTitle),
                        Text(snapshot.data[index].foodQuantity),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                        color: Colors.yellow, size: 30.0),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),))}}}));
```

hope this will help